# Há alguma forma de conectar um projeto feito em node.js direto a um dominio?

Tags: php, node.js

Bom o meu problema é porque tenho um site aberto na porta 80 e um projeto feito em node aberto na porta 8080. Possuo o dominio:https://erkonow.com, ao tentar acessar ele só direciona todos os subdomínios ao meu site(fazendo com que o meu aplicativo fique sem dominio), há alguma forma de eu fazer o aplicativo apontar pra um subdomínio? No caso: https://coup.erkonow.com, uso o Xampp.  Alguém consegue me explicar ou dar uma orientação?

> Uma outra saída possível seria uma forma de rodar *.php nesse meu app,
>   pois assim eu conseguiria encaixar a página que desejo ao aplicativo.

Comment: Cara, muda a porta do node pelo express (ou sei lá que web server você está usando com node), só isso. Põem porta 3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há nenhum problema em usar a porta 8080 para isso. Embora possível, você não precisa do Xampp para prover uma aplicação node, ele próprio cria um http server e escuta na porta definida.

Primeiro de tudo, sua aplicação deve ser acessível pela porta 8080, ou seja, a porta tem que estar aberta no seu server e a aplicação rodando na mesma. Depois disso, você precisa acessar o seu provedor de domínio e procurar lá como criar um subdomínio apontando para o seu IP do servidor juntamente com a porta 8080 (ex: 127.168.0.1:8080). Cada provedor irá fazer isso de uma forma diferente, e alguns nem permitem fazer isso pela interface, aí você teria que enviar um email para eles. Você provavelmente terá que configurar o CNAME para isso.

talvez ajude:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/